# Why my Windows suddenly encounters the error 'java.security.AccessControlException accessDeclaredMembers?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, jvm

I encountered a problem when I'm starting my Tomcat in Windows 7, which like a security problem:

`java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")`

How should I solve this problem? I follow somebody's instructions to add permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers"; in java.proxy file, but it causes another problem that java/lang/Object can't be found.

I just get very confused why this happened. Can anybody gives me ideas on fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: You have a few questions which you have marked as "urgent" - we try to discourage that here. It's worth noting that the community here is primarily made up of volunteers, and so questions will be answered by people who find them interesting, and only at their leisure. Also, bear in mind that questions marked as "urgent" are not prioritised over the others, so there is no point in adding it - it is just noise to be edited out.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error generated by the SecurityManager: you have code somewhere that is probably trying to use reflection to access an object's members directly, instead of using accessor methods or something like that.

This unlikely a problem with Tomcat, but with your application or a supporting library of some kind. Perhaps your application is not written to work properly under a SecurityManager (you'll probably want to fix that). In that case, if it's appropriate for your environment, you might just want to disable the SecurityManager.

(I would spend some time trying to figure out how to get your application to work under a SecurityManager. This can enhance security on your server even with a trusted web application.)

Comment: Thanks! I solved this problem just by using another tomcat server.